# How to create a jgz file

Tags: css, dojo

I am trying to modify a **style.css.jgz** file in an application that's using the Dojo framework.
To unpack the file I used 7-zip, extracted it and made the changes.
Now I would like to archive it back into the style.css.jgz file format.
I tried to do this by adding it to an archive using 7-zip using the gzip format, and then renamed style.css.gz to style.css.jgz but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it.

Thank you

Comment: I've never heard of the `jgz` extension before, certainly not in the context of Dojo in particular, but it is apparently an extension used for gzipped JavaScript files, so what you did to create it again sounds correct.  However, the fact that your file is `style.css.jgz` seems rather confusing, given that the `jgz` extension is apparently intended for JS files...

Comment: Thank you Ken, it's working ok so far, I just wandered if that was the right way to do it.